# Error: Non-optional output Excel (XLSX) missing

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-designautomation

I have an issue about exporting Excel using Design Automation. I currently don't know how to fix this, so your team can take a look. Here is  workitemsId : fa60d42304e6434c85fe973026db7f68

```
[04/06/2022 04:19:36] Start upload phase.
[04/06/2022 04:19:36] Error: Non-optional output [report.xlsx] is missing.
[04/06/2022 04:19:36] Error: An unexpected error happened during phase Publishing of job.
[04/06/2022 04:19:36] Job finished with result FailedMissingOutput
```

And here is Actities

```
{
    "id": "TestingActivity03",
    "commandLine": [
        "$(engine.path)\\\\revitcoreconsole.exe /i \"$(args[rvtFile].path)\" /l JPN /al \"$(appbundles[DemoTest02].path)\""
    ],
    "parameters": {
        "rvtFile": {
            "zip": false,
            "ondemand": false,
            "verb": "get",
            "description": "Input Revit model",
            "required": true,
            "localName": "$(rvtFile)"
        },
        "params": {
            "zip": false,
            "ondemand": false,
            "verb": "get",
            "description": "params",
            "required": true,
            "localName": "params.json"
        },
        
        "report": {
            "zip": false,
            "ondemand": false,
            "verb": "put",
            "description": "reports",
            "required": true,
            "localName": "report.xlsx"
        }
    },
    "engine": "Autodesk.Revit+2022",
    "appbundles": [
        "tanpv.DemoTest02+test"
    ],
    "description": "Add CBB from Revit file." }
```

I put in file revit into Bucket.
Thanks for reply!

Answer (score 0):

> [04/06/2022 04:19:36] Error: Non-optional output [report.xlsx] is missing.

This happens when an output parameter in an activity is specified, but the appbundle fails to generate the file with that local name. In your case you specified an output parameter `report` with local name `report.xlsx`. I checked the logs for the workitem id `fa60d42304e6434c85fe973026db7f68` did not find any clue as to why your code did not generate this file.

Maybe you could add some debug logs using `Console.WriteLine()` in your code and see for yourselves in the log file.

For how use excel in design automation, you may refer our blog [Design Automation - Revit Parameters Export & Import sample with Excel](https://forge.autodesk.com/ja/node/1414) and see [code samples](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/design.automation-nodejs-revit.parameters.excel).

Comment: I put the log into code and found out that the part error about (Object reference not set to an instance of an object) when I use the FilteredElementCollector(doc, doc.ActiveView.Id) to get the active Elements displayed on the imported revit file. Currently, I have not found a way to fix the above error to count the elements that appear on the screen

Comment: There is no concept of Active View in Design Automation (unlike Desktop Revit). You will have to provide the view Id explicitly if you know it or by looking for it.

Comment: I want to count all Element that are similar to the FilteredElementCollector Symbol family of Special Equipment. so can you give me a solution for the case of counting the number of elements displayed on the screen for Special Equipment.Thanks!

Comment: This looks like a separate question from the original. It gets tough to answer in comments. Could you post another question with details or reach out to forge.help[at]autodesk.com.